# Como pegar informações de outro programa em execução?

Tags: c#

**Atualizado**

Eu achei que minha pergunta iria ficar perdida e sinceramente nem vi que reabriram. Mas aproveitando que agora houve uma movimentação para atualizar sobre o meu app. Ele está sendo desenvolvido em C# e portanto, para Windows (mas posso mudar isso, mudando para C++, mas são só planos).

**Pergunta**

As **especificações**: preciso de uma função/procedimento/biblioteca/qualquer coisa que faça possível eu capturar informações de outro executável aberto. A ideia é que quando o meu aplicativo e um emulador (como o ZSNES) estejam aberto, eu possa recuperar informações dele, como:

- se a janela está focada ou não,
- quais teclas foram apertadas (com o meu aplicativo desfocado obviamente),
- pegar o título da janela já que sei o nome do processo,
- e, se possível, descobrir que jogo está sendo jogado (alguns emuladores registram um log, outros infelizmente não).

Comment: Dê uma estudada de como o [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) faz isso, pois ele tem um inspector que mostra uma diversidade de coisas sobre os processos em execução, além de servir naturalmente para automatizar e receber e injetar eventos nestes. Além disso, lembre-se que com os OSes 64 bits, muito provavelmente você precisará de um processo 64, pois se for 32, ele não acessará todos os processos da máquina.

Comment: Achei interessante esse programa! Provavelmente vá me auxiliar muito. Você acabou me ajudando duas vezes pois relembrei a palavra 'macro' e talvez seja um pouco do que eu precise!

Comment: Oi, Gabriel, em vez de buscar conflito, que não é legal quando a gente tá pedindo ajuda grátis de desconhecidos, sugiro uma lida no [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) (em pt). Você diz que pesquisou muito, então é legal editar a pergunta pra mostrar isso e tentar focar conforme o guia linkado. Boa sorte!

Comment: Mas não houve motivos nem para fecha-la, é uma pergunta clara que procura saber detalhes de um tal programa. Provavelmente nem leram quando eu disse que apesar da pesquisa não obtive retorno. Eu não sou de perguntar muito (pode ver pelo meu outro perfil do SO, que tenho mais de 1 ano de conta). Programo faz um bom tempo e nunca achei uma linguagem que faça isso. Como pôde ver, não obtive nenhuma resposta então não entendo como a denúncia dos senhores pode ser verdadeira.

Eu já li o link que me passou em outra oportunidade.

Comment: Oi Gabriel. Eu concordo com você que "baseada em opiniões" é um motivo de fechamento estranho para esta pergunta. Você não quer abrir uma discussão sobre o assunto no [meta]? Acredito que a pergunta pode muito bem ser reaberta se ambas as partes argumentarem. Só não vale partir para a ofensa. Outra coisa, não se sinta pessoalmente ofendido pela suspensão da pergunta, não é uma "denúncia" como você disse, nem nada contra você. É somente a opinião de cinco usuários do site.

Comment: Estas informações você obterá pelo Windows API. Ele pode ser acessado de várias linguagens.

Comment: @bfavaretto , de forma alguma eu discordo com as regras, eu entendo os motivos do site. Estou expondo para vocês que eu não procuro opiniões, procuro respostas objetivas e definitivas que possam resolver o meu problema. As regras não são problema, problema é que vocês combatem a subjetividade com subjetividade. Até agora ninguém apresentou um problema concreto. E desculpem por ter exagerado um pouco.

Comment: @Tony, poderia me dizer como?

Comment: O que estou dizendo é que levar o assunto para o meta aumenta as chances de resolver o problema, reabrir a pergunta (caso você não saiba, o meta é o lugar onde discutimos o site). Eu até concordo com você, mas 5 pessoas acharam outra coisa e seria bom discutir com elas (tenho certeza que a maioria ou todos esses usuários frequentam o meta).

Comment: Ah sim, entendo, vou ver como precedo até a noite, provavelmente farei isso mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: [Abri uma pergunta no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1945/escolher-linguagem-com-base-em-especifica%c3%a7%c3%b5es-fechada-como-opinativa) para discutir esta.

Comment: @Gabriel Você não especificou o OS no que isso tem que funcionar.

Comment: @Vincent Atualizei a pergunta com informações atualizadas.

Answer (score 1):

Este código abaixo lista os processos que estão sendo executados pelo Sistema Operacional:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Teste {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps ax"); // comando que vai pegar os processos

      BufferedReader resultado = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

      //mostra os resultados obtidos pelo comando "ps ax"
      String s;
      while ((s = resultado.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Link de um site com discussão mais aprofundado em outras linguagens:
[Detecção De Programas Rodando](http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/104287-deteccao-de-programa-rodando/)

Comment: Isso só funcionará num OS tipo ‘*nix’ (*BSD, OS X, Linux). Ainda por cima não da informação sobre as janelas abertas, qual está focada …

Comment: ok... mais o que eu forneci foi apenas parte da solução... a outra parte eu indiquei um site sobre uma discussão a cerca de tal problema.